# Ubuntu unresponsive after login

Tags: 14.04, mouse, lock-screen

After login in from lock-screen, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS remains unresponsive (or very slow) to mouse or keyboard input for about 15 seconds. The mouse is still moving but that is about it. After the delay, all previous mouse input and keystrokes are processed very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are too many start-up applications going.Try disabling some unnecessary ones.
You can do it with BUM software.(sudo apt-get install bum)
If you hesitate about necessity of apps just Google!

Comment: It might not be relevant, but I don't have this behavior after a boot, only after logging in after screen-lock